# Interesting behaviors when there is 'LF' in a Python script, a bug in interpreter?

Tags: python

When there is `+U000a`(the so-called 'LF') in a Python script, some funny things will happen.

On **Linux**, I've tried several cases (see below) with both Python2 and Python3, and it comes to me the following conclusion:

> 'LF' makes the successive token in *this visible line* ignored, but will execute next line.

Is it covered in the Python spec, or it's a bug in the interpreter?

To me, this is at least an issue for the parser since an 'LF' shouldn't have the semantics like above; but there seem no big issue for daily use.

Since 'LF' is not printable, I attached the screenshot, where `^@` represents 'LF'(+U000a). For those who are interested in trying, I provided [gist](https://gist.github.com/HongxuChen/51f8ba00d84a5b41517e83e089aedb7c) (need to git clone it).

[image]

### update according to comments

`import test_2` works as described with python2 REPL, but will cause `ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes` in python3; while running directly both are as described.

Comment: Could you add what OS you are on? I'm currently on a Windows machine and when running your gist I immediately get a `Syntax Error` error for the first line.

Comment: @alxwrd Linux. maybe that's due to the different treatments of '\n', '\r\n', '\r' ...

Comment: So I was running the gist from a Python console session because that's what I was in, and an `import` causes a syntax error. However running `python test_2.py` from the command line reproduces it as you described.

Comment: @alxwrd not sure why, `import test_2` works as described with python2, but will cause `ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes` in python3; but running directly both are as described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a LF U+000A. That's a NUL, U+0000, which shows up as `^@` in `vim`, `emacs`, or `less`--a LF would show up as `^J` if it showed up that way, but LFs show up as line breaks. I am *not surprised* that Python handles NUL bytes in source code in a weird way, since it's very common for NUL bytes in text files to be handled that way in programs written in C.

It appears to be a defect in the Python parser itself. If you try to replicate the behavior in the Python interpreter,

```
import parser
parser.st2list(parser.expr('"hello"\0"goodbye"'))
```

You'll get an error:

```
TypeError: expr() argument 1 must be str without null characters, not str
```

This, to me, indicates that the behavior is unintended and loading code from a file bypasses this check.  I would consider this a bug in the Python interpreter.

This only happens if the file in question is the main program. If you `import` a file containing NUL bytes, you will get an error. It appears that this happens because Python reads the main source file line-by-line using `fgets()` (see [tokenizer.c:1022](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Parser/tokenizer.c#L1022)) which returns a NUL-terminated string. If the line contains a NUL byte, it will be truncated.

Comment: oops, i was stupid that i didn't realize i made such a mistake that it is actually 'NUL'! then that is only a "defect".

Comment: why `Python3` read the main source file line-by-line? shouldn't it still read the whole file and firstly check the syntax firstly?

Comment: ok, seems that python interpreter doesn't do any syntax check before running on a py script...

Comment: off topic, tried a few examples about python's interpretation, find another interesting behavior: `python -c 'V-W -99999**999999'` will still execute the computation part, **after** it finds out that `V` is not defined.

Comment: even when there are multiple lines in between... see [gist](https://gist.github.com/HongxuChen/51f8ba00d84a5b41517e83e089aedb7c#file-test_3-py)